# Что делать если библиотеки нет в репозитории maven?

Tags: java, maven

Я хочу использовать в Maven проекте имплементацию OpenMP под Java - либо JaMP, либо omp4j, но не могу прописать зависимости, так как они обе отсутствуют в репозитории самого Maven. Что можно сделать?

Comment: скачать jar-ник и заинстоллить в локальный мавен-репозиторий `mvn file-install`

Comment: А если нет информации о том, какой artefactId, groupId и версия у jar, могу ли я при инсталяции свои какие-то значения проставить?

Comment: конечно, потом их укажите в своем pom-нике.

Answer (score 6):

Для серьезных больших проектов, самый правильный способ - поднять собственный репозиторий. На выбор, например, есть [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) и [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/solution-overview).

Если это невозможно, то можно установить нужный jar в локальный репозиторий Maven. Про это на сайте Maven есть [специальная документация](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html). Вкратце, достаточно просто запустить в терминале строчку:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

В ней вы можете указать правильную группу и артефакт.

В более-менее большом проекте (без собственного репозитория Maven) быстро накапливается большое количество таких библиотек. Мы в качестве конвенции (которую всем рекомендую) выбрали следущее: в корне любого проекта должна находиться директория lib, в которой должны лежать все jar'ки необходимые для установки, а рядом с ними должен находиться скрипт .bat (для Windows) и скрипт .sh (UNIX/GNU/Linux) в которых прописаны все вызовы install-file, необходимые для полной работоспособности проекта.

Очень важно ударение на "полную работоспособность". У нас были случаи, когда непонятно как полученный .m2 репозиторий передавался из рук в руки как реликвия, потому что если бы он вдруг потерялся, запуск проекта превратился бы в челленж на две недели длиной. Так быть не должно, вся процедура установки должна быть записана в специальном скрипте в папке lib, для всех активных платформ.