# Ошибка во время сборки maven (артефакт находится во внешнем каталоге)

Tags: java, maven

Старый проект переводится на maven, но вот библиотеку для **tuprolog**, не смог найти.

Взял бибилиотеку из старого проекта, которая не понятно как была создана (надо сказать, там внутри я нашел каталоги eclipse, ide, вообщем структура странная, не как обычно, как будто данный проект был кем-то сильно изменен).

Я пытался подключить с **maven** похожую библиотеку

```java
    <dependency>
            <groupId>it.unibo.alice.tuprolog</groupId>
            <artifactId>tuprolog</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Но в ней не оказалось нескольких нужных классов...

```java
import alice.tuprolog.NullTerm;
import alice.tuprolog.SpyEvent;
import alice.tuprolog.SpyListener;
```

Пришлось сделать вот такую конструкцию

```java
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>alice.tuprolog</artifactId>
            <groupId>tuprolog</groupId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>2P_1.0.0</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/2P_1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

При компиляции, появляются критические предупреждения

> Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.its:common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for tuprolog:alice.tuprolog:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/2P_1.0.0.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 62, column 25
>   It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
>   For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

**Обновление**

я создал pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tuprolog</groupId>
    <artifactId>alice.tuprolog</artifactId>
    <version>2P_1.0.0</version>

  <name>prolog</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>

    </build>
</project>
```

Затем выполнил команду

```java
mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=E:\!_svn\dec\common\lib\prolog\pom.xml –Dfile E:\!_svn\dec\common\lib\prolog\2P_1.0.0.jar r  -DgroupId=tuprolog -DartifactId=alice.tuprolog   -Dversion=2P_1.0.0   -Dpackaging=jar   -DgeneratePom=true
```

получил ошибку

> No plugin found for prefix 'E' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (e:!_Insta
>   ll!_apache-mvn-local-repo), central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)] -> [Help 1]

такая же ошибка и вот при такой команде

```java
mvn install:install-file –Dfile=2P_1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=tuprolog -DartifactId=alice.tuprolog -Dversion=2P_1.0.0
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project alice.tuprolog: The parameters 'file' for goal org.apache.maven.
>   plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]

добавил кавычки

```java
mvn install:install-file -DpomFile="E:\!_svn\declarant\common\lib\prolog\pom.xml" –Dfile="E:\!_svn\declarant\common\lib\prolog\2P_1.0.0.jar" r  -DgroupId=tuprolog -DartifactId=alice.tuprolog   -Dversion=2P_1.0.0   -Dpackaging=jar   -DgeneratePom=true
```

> No plugin found for prefix '?Dfile=E' in the current project and in
>   the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the repositories [local (e:\
>   !_Install!_apache-mvn-local-repo), central
>   (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

Затем оказалось, что ошибка была в неверном символе, вот такой код выполнился 
без  ошибок

```java
mvn install:install-file -DpomFile="E:/!_svn/declarant/common/lib/prolog/pom.xml" -Dfile="E:/!_svn/declarant/common/lib/prolog/2P_1.0.0.jar" -Dgro
upId=tuprolog -DartifactId=alice.tuprolog -Dversion=2P_1.0.0  -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

> [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ alice.tuprolog ---
>   [INFO] Installing E:!_svn\dec\common\lib\prolog\2P_1.0.0.jar to e:!_Install!_apache-mvn-local-repo\tuprolog\alice.tuprolog\2P_1.0.0\alice.tuprolog-2P_1.0.0.jar
>   [INFO] Installing E:!_svn\dec\common\lib\prolog\pom.xml to e:!_Install!_apache-mvn-local-repo\tuprolog\alice.tuprolog\2P_1.0.0\alice.tuprolog-2P_1.0.0.pom
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Но по факту, в указанном месте есть данный файл, но проект его не видит

В конфигурационном файле Maven указано

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">



  <localRepository>e:\!_Install\!_apache-mvn-local-repo\</localRepository>
```

а по факту, все основные артефакты данного много модульного проекта, находятся в другом месте.

А prolog**.jar был скопирован в то место, которое указано в конфигурационном файле **maven**

Я использую **intellij idea 2019**

Подскажите как это исправить..

**Решено**

Указал в конфигурационном файле **maven** такой же путь к локальному репозиторию, как и в Intellij idea.

Кроме этого, решил создать репозиторий, прямо в проекте maven.

[Создание репозитория в проекте](http://java-online.ru/maven-repo.xhtml)

в модуле, котором нужен артифакт, в файле pom.xml, указал следующее

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>dec</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.dec</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.its</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>common</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository</id>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>file://${basedir}/lib/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

**/lib/repository** - эту директорию поместил в корень модуля.

Затем командой (приведена выше) снова собрал туда артефакт), только в команду добавил аргумент

```java
-DlocalRepositoryPath="E:/!_svn/dec/common/lib/repository"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemPath` вроде как используется для [системных зависимостей](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies). Т.е. там должен быть указан путь, который будет доступен на машине, на которой проект будет запускаться. У вас же указан путь внутри исходного кода, что кажется Maven странным.

Проблема с «левыми» библиотеками достаточно распространена. Даже вопрос есть: [Что делать если библиотеки нет в репозитории maven?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488777/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-maven)

Обычно люди устанавливают зависимость в локальный репозиторий на компьютере:

```
mvn install:install-file –Dfile=2P_1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=tuprolog -DartifactId=alice.tuprolog -Dversion=2P_1.0.0
```

После этого ее можно будет подключить без `systemPath`:

```
<dependency>
     <artifactId>alice.tuprolog</artifactId>
     <groupId>tuprolog</groupId>
     <version>2P_1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Недостаток: всем, кто будет собирать проект нужно будет сначала установить библиотеку.

Более умный вариант: развернуть свой собственный репозиторий (Nexus, например) и складировать в нем все такие библиотеки. Тогда все люди в компании смогут собрать проект, проставив ссылку на репозиторий.

Другие варианты кажутся мне более сомнительными. Возможно получится декомпилировать 
библиотеку и включить в maven как подпроект. Также есть вариант объявления репозитория внутри проекта ([Maven add jars through systemPath/system but not added to war or anywhere else](http://Maven%20add%20jars%20through%20systemPath/system%20but%20not%20added%20to%20war%20or%20anywhere%20else)), только при этом нужно будет распространять JAR вместе с исходным кодом.